# Index array with the result of .nonzero()

Tags: python, numpy

I am having difficulties selecting rows using two condition in Numpy. The following code does not return the intended output

```
tot_length=0.3
steps=0.1
start_val=0.0
list_no =np.arange(start_val, tot_length, steps)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(*[list_no for _ in range(3)], sparse=True)
a = ((x>=y) & (y>=z)).nonzero() # this maybe the problem
```

output

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]))
```

whereas, the intended output

```
[[0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.1 0.  0. ]
 [0.1 0.1 0. ]
 [0.1 0.1 0.1]
 [0.2 0.  0. ]
 [0.2 0.1 0. ]
 [0.2 0.1 0.1]
 [0.2 0.2 0. ]
 [0.2 0.2 0.1]
 [0.2 0.2 0.2]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ndarray.nonzero` as well as `np.where` return tuples of arrays of indices. This makes unpacking those indices into separate arrays, which can then be used to index along a given axis. Stacking them up into a 2D array is trivial though, simply build a new array and transpose as:

```
ix = np.array(((x>=y) & (y>=z)).nonzero()).T
```

Then you can easily use the array of indices to index `list_no` as:

```
list_no[ix]
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.1, 0. ],
       [0. , 0.2, 0. ],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0. ],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0. ],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.1],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0. ],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.1],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]])
```